# Best axe for making kindling and little work

Tags: camping, fire-starting, firewood

I am looking for the best type of axe for being able to chops already split wood into smaller kindling, while also being capable of chopping down small trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is called a "carpenters axe" today. My father called it a "boat axe" as one you could reasonably bring in a canoe. Larger than a hatchet, smaller than a regular felling axe and not nearly as heavy.

Comment: Where I come from, a carpenter's axe is specifically referring to one with an (almost) straight blade, and often a nail puller or hammering surface on the back. (Nevertheless, the recommendation is good, I use one for a similar purpuse.)

Comment: In British English the typical "hand axe"s sounds like that ,though a carpenter's axe might have more of a beard. A "hatchet" here tends to be particularly short-handled.